# Munmap_chunk() error, cannot understand pointer behavior

Tags: c++, string, pointers, std

I am making a simple sorting program with templates and are struggling with string case.
Code:

```
template<typename typ>
void Join_Segments(typ *tab, int begin1, int begin2, int end2, bool(*Compare)(typ arg1, typ arg2)){
  typ *joined = new typ[end2-begin1+1]; // sorted elements arrray
  int c1, c2, ci;                        // counters

  for(c1=begin1, c2=begin2, ci=0; c1<begin2 && c2<=end2; ci++){         
    if(!Compare(tab[c1], tab[c2])){ joined[ci]=tab[c2]; c2++;}
    else{ joined[ci]=tab[c1]; c1++;}
  }
  while(c1<begin2){joined[ci]=tab[c1]; c1++; ci++;}
  while(!(c2>end2)){joined[ci]=tab[c2]; c2++; ci++;}

  for(int i=0; i<(end2-begin1+1); i++) tab[begin1+i]=joined[i];
  delete joined;
}
```

So this is working wonderful for integers. And it is working for strings as long as I remove the "delete joined" line, but that is pretty crucial for sorting large arrays.
GDB backtrace log:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x40022424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x40022424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x40171827 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#2  0x40174c53 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#3  0x401ac993 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x402a9a5c "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#4  0x401b6e7a in malloc_printerr (action=<optimized out>, 
    str=0x402a9a80 "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer", ptr=0x90551d4)
    at malloc.c:4996
#5  0x401b6f48 in munmap_chunk (p=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2816
#6  0x400849df in operator delete(void*) ()
   from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x08049518 in Join_Segments<std::string> (tab=0x905500c, begin1=0, begin2=2, 
    end2=2, Compare=0x80490a6 <_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z2Nli()+8>) at scalanie.hh:11
#8  0x080491f5 in Mergesort<std::string> (tab=0x905500c, begin=0, 
    end=2, Compare=0x80490a6 <_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z2Nli()+8>) at scalanie.hh:32
#9  0x08048ee1 in main () at main.cpp:11
```

I think this is probably caused by std::string assignment magic but I can't figure out how to fix it. Tried a lot of things like casting right hand side of assigment to (const typ&) so it will copy it according to [that documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) but it's still trying blindly. Could anyone help me with this?

I can provide full code but it's not visually identical (english is not my native language and I changed functions/var names here) so it may be harder to read.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `delete[]` since it's an array, but that's just a general thing, haven't looked at the code with enough attention.

Comment: Wow, just wow, I was that stupid. Thanks, it works now!

By the way, in my case 'joined' shouldn't be a pointer to the first element in the array? And shouldn't 'delete joined' only delete first istead of throwing errors? I'm just curious.

PS. You should add it as an answer so I can tag this as resolved and not bother other fine folks here anymore.

Comment: Added and answer :) Well what you have in your code is the pointer to the first element. But as for this `shouldn't 'delete joined' only delete first istead of throwing errors` - as I stated, standard says that mixing incorrect types of `new/delete` will cause undefined behavior, so you should not rely on anything to happen the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `delete[]` since you are deleting an array allocated with `new[]`. Mixing incorrect types of `new/delete` can lead to undefined behavior according to the standard which I guess is what you are seeing.